# add 2 to list [[23,34],[34,23]]

Tags: python, list

I have a list looks something like `[[23,34],[43,23]]` and I want to add an int to each number so say if i want to add 2 to it the list becomes `[[25,36],[45,25]]`

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Nested for loops? List comprehension in list comprehension?

Comment: @mgilson That question has been [banned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic). I could have your comment removed instantly with a flag!

Comment: @jamylak -- Yeah, I just looked it up on meta.  I hadn't seen that before.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I'll try to behave better in the future O:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> nums = [[23,34],[43,23]]
>>> [[y + 2 for y in x] for x in nums]
[[25, 36], [45, 25]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[23,34],[43,23]])
b = a + 2 #inplace:  a += 2
```

Comment: @jamylak -- That really depends on why OP wants this.  It's a bit overkill to require `numpy` as a dependency if you only need to do this once (and you actually *need* lists after the fact).  But if OP will do a bunch of numerical calculations, `numpy` is fantastic.

Comment: Ok I should rephrase that "Versatile solution"